# Mainboard doesn't support my CPU

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

I've bought a new Mainboard Asus h61m-g and I have got some issues with it namely that my CPU intel core i7 2600 is not supported. At the start of booting it gives me message: This CPU is not supported!
I checked if my Mainboard supports my CPU and it was perfectly fine 
http://www.asus.com/supportonly/H61M-G/HelpDesk_CPU/
and also upgraded BIOS but still "This CPU is not supported".
I don't know what the issue might me.

btw. OS: win10 64bit

Comment: What version BIOS did you update to?

Comment: Bent pins in the socket? The motherboard may not be recognizing your processor.

Comment: Have you updated bios on your motherboard at all?  I had a similar issue with the i7 2600 years ago and it was due to the bios being updated.

Comment: I updated my Mainboard to version 0312 and it's the latest version I could find on their website and yes I am sure I did update it
If there were bent pins wouldn't my pc start at all ?

Comment: You need to verify 0312 is installed by entering the bios and making sure.

Comment: I did m8 and I don't even need to update my bios because my last bios should provide support of my intel core i7 2600 CPU but I did update it anyway

Answer (score 0):

Have you definitely successfully installed the BIOS update?  Following the link you specified above and clicking the "Go" button for your CPU - I arrived at the following link for a BIOS upgrade:
http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/H61M-G/H61M-G-ASUS-0312.zip

To check your bios version, you can put your old CPU back in, boot to windows, open PowerShell and enter the following command:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS
```

This will give you the currently installed BIOS version for your machine.  You can also look at the System Information Tool (Windows Key + R > msinfo32 > OK) and look for your BIOS Version.

If your BIOS is up to date and your old CPU boots up fine, then the chances are that there is damage to your new CPU - static, bent pins etc and it will need to be returned/replaced.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I didn't buy new CPU. It's my old one. It works fine with another old Motherboard and I couldn't detect any damages on my new Motherboard.
When PC is about to start there is a screen with information of my CPU BIOS etc. and I am sure I installed new verson 0312